# What is the shape of external rays landing on fixed points in case of quadratic discrete dynamical system?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

In case of parabolic discrete dynamical system based on [the complex quadratic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_quadratic_polynomial)

fc(z) = z^2 + c

some external rays land on alfa fixed point. 
[image: Hera are 34 external rays for rotational number 1/34]
Hera are 34 external rays landing on fixed point for rotational number 1/34.

c = 0.258368 + 0.001564*i

1. It seems that these rays spiral around fixed point. Is it true or it is only some numerical error ?
2. What can be said about shape of these external rays in case of rotational numer 1/n ?
3. how can I compute points on external ray near parabolic fixed point ?

TIA

Comment: Answer only to the first question: Here c = 0.258368 + 0.001564*i and it is not a parabolic parameter. Here rotational number = 0.02941078600973229. It should be 1/34=0.02941176470588235 and the difference = 9.786961500633795e-7. So the image is good ( rays near alfa are approximated by straight line) but it is not parabolic case).

Comment: I'm very much still learning "landing rays".  I got the 34 Landing rays to work for the Julia for n=34 parabolic point, which is very close to your "c".  It works better for C=0.258385930 + 0.00148483651i, which is the hyperbolic center.  I used Wolf Jung's Mandel program to play external rays, plotting 1/(2^34-1),2/(2^34-1)....2^33/(2^34-1) for the angles. It looks more or less like your picture.  Again, still learning...  The parabolic case is going to have extremely slow convergence, so I would imagine the rays would need to get very very close to the unit circle.  Hyperbolic case easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Complex Dynamics by Carleson and Gamelin page 40 ther is a :
"The gap between 2 consecutive petals is contained in a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) bounded by curves with :

$|\theta - \theta'_k|  \sim  |z|^{1/p}$

"

It should describe shape of these rays.

Comment: I need to go back and reread Carleson & Gamelin's book, and see if I can understand more now.